# I want make image clickable in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-mix

when I click the image I want to add some class to it.
I am doing it following way:-

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img 
        :image_id="image.id" 
        :src="'/storage/images/'+image.name"
        @click="select(image)"
        :class="{
           'selected': image.selected
        }"
    />
</div>


select(image) {
     for (let i = 0; i < this.imageData.length; i++) {
         if(image.id == this.imageData[i].id) {
             this.imageData[i].selected = true
          }
     }
}
```

when I click it doesn't call the method.
I checked it by add `console.log()` in `select()` method.

suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to a single image: https://jsfiddle.net/vqzyx6hn/

```
<div id="app">
 <div class="thumbnail">
    <img 
        :image_id="image.id" 
        src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/47/139324914_374969bd81.jpg"
        @click="select(image)"
        :class="{
           'selected': image.selected
        }"
    />
</div>
</div>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    image : {
        id: 1,
      selected: false,

    }
  },
  methods: {
    select: function(image){
    alert('it is working')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: I did it as you said. it called function but class is not adding

Answer (score 1):

You need to register `select` as a method in your script part:

```
<script>
export default {
 methods: {
   select(image) {
     for (let i = 0; i < this.imageData.length; i++) {
         if(image.id == this.imageData[i].id) {
             this.imageData[i].selected = true
          }
     }
   }
 }
}
</script>
```